# "Sticky notes" in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

I would like to put in my matplotlib plot, some text with information or reminders like "stickynotes". This is my code until now:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1);
y = np.sin(x)

plt.text(2 , 0.5, s = "Here´s a note", bbox = dict(facecolor = "red"))


plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

As you can see, i put one "stickynote" using one of the modules of the matplotlib library, but what i want to do is to put the "note" and displace it using the mouse, around the plot. Is there any module that i could use for this? How can i achieve this?

Thank you for your time and answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at draggable annotations.

As a quick example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1);
y = np.sin(x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ann = ax.annotate("Here's a note", xy=(2, 0.5), bbox=dict(facecolor='yellow'))
ann.draggable()

ax.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this helped me a lot. I was able to drag the note, but you can only move it once. But, it was what i wanted to do. Thank you a lot.

Comment: You should be able to move it more than once... Something must not be working correctly.

Comment: Do you know if there is any way that i could use a 'QTextEdit' from PyQt4 to write a note, and get that text for the stickynote? Or just how to get the text from it? By the way, it was a configuration problem, now i can move it every time.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Joe's answer, the other avenue is to assign a function to the "clicking on the canvas" event if you have some additional work you want to do on the back end:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def click(event):
    global note
    note_x  = event.xdata
    note_y = event.ydata

    # remove your old note
    note.remove()
    # add a new one and redraw the figure
    note = plt.text(note_x , note_y, s = "Here's a note", bbox = dict(facecolor = "red"))
    plt.draw()


fig = plt.figure()
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', click)     


x = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1);
y = np.sin(x)


plt.plot(x,y)
note = plt.text(2 , 0.5, s = "Here's a note", bbox = dict(facecolor = "red"))
plt.show()
```

Comment: That code won't work in its current form - you need to redraw the canvas inside your callback

Comment: Oops, thanks for the catch. Coding in Spyder let's you take shortcuts sometimes... I've edited to explicitly show and redraw the figure.